# Время между кликами, Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток. Работа с Unity. При клике вызывается условие `if-else`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы условие выполнялось, если между двумя кликами прошло менее 3 сек? Что-то не могу сообразить как это сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float lastTime;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastTime > 3f)
        {
            MyAction();
            lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        }
    }
}
```